# If this text exists, change this text HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I would like to change text depending on whether other text appears on my web page.

Essentially, if

```
<h3 class="lato dark bold title">Disneyland Paris</h3>
```

contains the words Disneyland Paris

change the inner HTML of

```
<span class="orange size22"><b>Call For Price</b></span>
```

to

```
<span class="orange size22"><b>my new text</b></span>
```

I can't change the class or id on these elements due to the system we are using.

Anyone know if this is possible using basic css/js logic?

Comment: Could you please provide more informations ? HTML for example ?

Comment: sorry, didnt realise it used html as formatting, now quoted in.

Comment: if the answers below do not solve, i think you should atleast tell us why and change your question

Comment: i've updated the question to hopefully explain a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the header has a value and then change span accordingly.

HTML:

```
<h3 id='mainHeader' class="lato dark bold title">contains text</h3>

<span id='firstSpan' class="orange size22"><b>this text</b></span>
```

JS:

```
var mainHeader = document.getElementById('mainHeader');
var firstSpan = document.getElementById('firstSpan');
console.log(mainHeader.textContent)

if(mainHeader.textContent.length > 0){ //check if the header has a value
    firstSpan.textContent= 'newText'; //and then change span accordingly
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/nVyXS/1729/

EDIT:

I think you want to check if the header string contains a smaller string. Do it this way :

```
var mainHeader = document.getElementById('mainHeader');
var firstSpan = document.getElementById('firstSpan');
var mainHeaderString = mainHeader.textContent; //get header string
var stringToCheck = 'contain text'; //string to check

if (mainHeaderString.indexOf(stringToCheck) > -1) { //check if string is in header tag
  firstSpan.textContent= 'newText';
}
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/nVyXS/1731/

And finally, if you can't have id's, so you use the class :

```
<h3  class="lato dark bold title">does this contain text</h3>    
<span  class="orange size22"><b>this text</b></span>

var mainHeader = document.getElementsByClassName('lato dark bold title');
var firstSpan = document.getElementsByClassName('orange size22');

console.log(mainHeader[0].textContent);

var mainHeaderString = mainHeader[0].textContent; //gets the first element of the returned array, i.e your first elemt with a classlist that contains : 'lato dark bold title'
var stringToCheck = 'contain text'
if (mainHeaderString.indexOf(stringToCheck) > -1) {
  firstSpan[0].textContent = 'newText'; //sets the first elements text (i.e with a classlist that contains :'orange size22' ) to what ever you want it to be
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/nVyXS/1738/

Notice I use getElementsByClassName(''). This returns an array of elements with the chosen class name to match. So later I use getElementsByClassName('')[0]. So this returns the first element from the array :)

As mentioned in the comments there could be consequences of using innerHTML. It's slower and textContent just uses straight text.

Comment: I got this working in fiddle to how I want it, the idea is correct. But we don't have any Id's, and I can't get it to check class. I tried getElementsbyClassName("lato dark bold title"); but this didn't work ?? - @thisOneGuy

Comment: @david.roberts added to the answer, is that okay ?

Comment: You shouldn't use `innerHTML`, as it can have unintended side effects; use `textContent` instead.

Comment: I'd feel a lot better if you just replaced all instances of innerHTML with textContent; I'd give you an upvote if you did. Right now, I can't endorse bad practice.

Comment: works great in fiddle, but live nothing is changing. console is saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined ?? @thisOneGuy

Comment: @david.roberts: Take a look at the note in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35460756/959552). This error is due to the fact, that selector doesn't match what is should.

Comment: @Przemek I read the link in your answer but tbh, I am totally lost and confused. I want the code in the HTML of the page and to change all elements with that class. I feel I'm missing something blindly obvious ? :S

Comment: as @Przemek said this should not be used this way as in a live example, as the first element, ie the one at [0] in the array brought back from searching for the classes, will probably be something else. You really should put id's on your elements to make things easier. Also, if you want this in your html, just wrap the javascript in <script> tags below where you create the html elements. If you're finding this confusing, maybe you should write a few tests yourself so you know what youre working with

Comment: Better still, provide us with a working JSFiddle that's closer to what youre encountering, that way we know exactly what your problem is. Should be very simple fix

Comment: @david.roberts: I edited my answer, so all instances of such `span`s as in your questions change. If it won't work, provide us with wider example (more surrounding code).

Comment: @david.roberts do you have a container for these header and span tags ? If you do, just select that container by ID and then you can go through each one of it's children to change the values

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

**jQuery way:**

*HTML:*

```
<h3 class="lato dark bold title">certain text</h3>
<span class="orange size22"><b>this text</b></span>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
<script>
  if ($('h3').text() == "certain text") {
    $('span b').text('new text');
  }
</script>
```

**Pure JavaScript way:**

*HTML:*

```
<h3 id="title"class="lato dark bold title">certain text</h3>
<span class="orange size22"><b id="subtitle" >this text</b></span>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
<script>
  if (document.getElementById('title').innerHTML == "certain text" ) {
     document.getElementById('subtitle').innerHTML = 'new text';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: but isn't this just detecting the length of the h3 and not the text within it?

Comment: the innerHTML picks the content inside the tags

Comment: but it needs to specifically check that the tag contains certain text -

Comment: would ` if(mainHeader[i].innerHTML.indexOf("contains text") != -1){ `   work?

Comment: You shouldn't use `innerHTML`, as it can have unintended side effects; use `textContent` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Pure and simple JavaScript way with working example and your nomenclature:

```js
if (document.querySelector('h3.lato.dark.bold.title').textContent === 'Disneyland Paris') {
  var elementsToChange = document.querySelectorAll('span.orange.size22 > b');
  for (var i = 0; i < elementsToChange.length; i++) {
    elementsToChange[i].textContent = 'my new text';
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 class="lato dark bold title">Disneyland Paris</h3>
<span class="orange size22"><b>Call For Price</b></span>
<span class="orange size22"><b>Call For Price</b></span>
```

### NOTE

In the above snippet I refer to:

- `h3` from your question, as to the `h3` with classes lato, dark, bold and title;
- `b` in `span` from your question, as to all the `b`s being a child of `span` with classes orange and size22 in the entire document.

In real application you will probably have to change those selectors to something else, because they can match something else. You may want to take a look at [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for that (if it helps you: you can use it just like if you were writing CSS selector).

**EDIT**: According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457188/if-this-text-exists-change-this-text-html-css-js/35460756#comment58618764_35457414), author wants to change all multiple occurrences of such `span`s. Snippet edited to fit.